# Recommend way to start a php session in an EE module?

Tags: module, ee, 2.9

What is the recommended way to start a php session in an EE module.

I am using EE 2.9.4 and have a custom module. In the constructor I call session_start(). When I look at the cookie that gets created the cookie path is wrong. It is set to the path of the page instead of "/".

When I call session_start in a plain php app the default behavior of session_start is to set the cookie path at root "/".

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650799/recommend-way-to-start-a-php-session-in-an-expresionengine-module/42656912#42656912

Answer (score 0):

ExpressionEngine sets the PHP session cookie to use identical parameters to match the application's cookie settings. In v3, you can find this under Settings > Security & Privacy. In v2, it would be in Admin > Security and Privacy > Cookie Settings.

If the [Cookie Path](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/settings/security-privacy.html#path) is left blank, then PHP will base the cookie off of the path in the URL at the time the cookie is set. You can make sure all of your cookies are available at the root by setting the Cookie Path to `/`.